# Can`t throw an object aligned with vertical angle of the camera with .velocity = transform.TransformDirection( Vector3.forward)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> I made a script for throwing a grabbed object, but i don`t know how to make it so the object is being launched depending on the vertiacal angle of the camera, not just forward. What paramentr should i give to the TransformDirection? Here is the code

```
void throwObject(float pushForce){  
        carrying = false;
        carriedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * pushForce);
        carriedObject.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().useGravity = true;          
        carriedObject = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to take into account the camera's X rotation.  So, something like:

```
carriedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce(
    (Vector3.forward * pushForce) + (Vector3.up * 
    -Camera.main.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x));
```

Firstly, how this should work: X, in most cases, should be the axis at which the camera is able to look "up and down."  If it's not, change it to whatever axis the camera rotates on to look up and down.  By checking the X rotation of the camera, we get it's angle.  Then, we make it negative, because by default a positive rotation on a camera is actually looking down.  You also just might want to encapsulate

```
(Vector3.forward * pushForce) + (Vector3.up * 
-Camera.main.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x)
```

with a `transform.TransformDirection()` statement so that you can be at any rotation.  It might not be necessary, but I'm not quite sure.

Secondly, it's a better idea to use `Rigidbody.AddForce()` than directly setting `Rigidbody.velocity`, or so I hear.

I hope this helped you out :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but now the objects fly directly up or down depending on the sign of the Camera.main..., and start moving in the z direction when on the ground. I tryed experimenting with different combinations of these parameters, but it doesn`t want to work like i want it to unfortunately

Comment: Then I would try going back from `AddForce()` to `velocity`.  I'm positive that the concept is right, just not that sure on how to "apply" it.  I'm sorry that this didn't work first try.

Comment: I tried it with velocity, the problem is that the trajectory of the throw is fixed. I want to throw the object from the center of the screen straight. RIght now it is thrown with a fixed angle, so i can`t launch it directly above the head. Here is the full code http://pastebin.com/zyYiXNE3 And again, thanks for your support

Comment: I finally figured it out, AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward * pushFirce * 100)

Comment: Aha!  Yes, that would make sense :)